# How to make ship shoot?

Tags: python, pgzero

```
import pygame
WIDTH = 1000
HEIGHT = 500
bg=Actor("bgbgbg")
ship = Actor('ship_f')
ship_en=Actor('ship_enemy')
blaster1=Actor('blaster')
a=random.randint(2,4)
def draw():
    screen.clear()
    bg.draw()
    ship.draw()
    ship_en.draw()
    blaster1.draw()
blaster1.pos=-1000,-1000
ship.pos=50,250
ship_en.pos=1500,random.randint(20,480)
def update():
    print (ship_en.left)
    ship_en.left+=-20
    if ship_en.left < -  250:
        ship_en.pos=1500,random.randint(20,480)
def on_mouse_move(pos):
    mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    ship.pos=mouse_pos
```

Hello! I need to make shooting in my little game. The main goal is when i click my mouse, my ship shoots with blaster. How can i make a couple of blasters shooting at one time with one image and shoot directly from ship's postition?

Comment: detect mouse press, then duplicate Your shots, set their direction and start position and then blit them, also remember to delete them once they reach the edge otherwise it may lag

Comment: This is not [Pygame](https://www.pygame.org/news), it is [Pygame Zero](https://pygame-zero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). You have to use the [tag:pgzero] tag instead of the [tag:pygame] tag.